# Can RESTful client enable SSL/TLS *without* "user" authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https

I am developing an application consisting of RESTful services communicating over HTTP. Spring Boot is providing the underlying support.

As part of my investigations, I am currently working with a known working example of a RESTful client and server that uses HTTPS/SSL/TLS ( https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-tls-example ). I have managed to successfully build, run the example and verify that it works.

Part of the client security configuration code involves setting up basic authorization on a `org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder`.

I am under the impression (perhaps incorrect) that authentication is not required. Am I right or wrong in this assumption?

I have been experimenting with trying to remove the authentication and when I run the example, the server emits output indicating that the action is "Unauthorized". On the client side, I get a 201 response (for a POST), but the JSON data does not contain the data I expect.

Comment: While you can do TLS without authentication (no certificate), are you sure that is what you want? Because it means you are encrypting the exchange (great, no bystander can see what is exchanged) but then you have no idea who you are sending this exchange too... so this is easily hijacked.

Comment: I guess I need to clarify a little more. I was wondering if it could be done without needing to involve the concept of a user/password. After some more experimentation, the answer is yes. The server does have a cert and the client has a truststore containing the public key of the server's cert CA.